# LaTeX Numbering in Counters Appears to have Changed

Tags: numbering

I work on a project called OpenIntro (http://openintro.org), and we have created custom numbering for tables and figures within an open-source textbook so that tables and figures use a common counter. Recently, it seems the way LaTeX handles counters has changed. I now only see even numbers (1.2, 1.4, 1.6) where before there was regular numbering (1.1, 1.2, 1.3).

Any idea on if there have been updates to the way counters are handled in LaTeX? If so, was a bug introduced or a bug fixed? I'm trying to assess whether I should be waiting for a fix or implement a fix myself. I don't want to do the latter if whatever changed is soon reverted.

In case anyone wants to take a closer look at the code used for the counters, the source files are at

http://www.openintro.org/stat/textbook.php (click the second main link, then scroll down to see the LaTeX source files link)

The counter code is in "extraTeX > style > styleV5-print.tex" around line 155.

Thanks for any tips or info you can offer!

David

Comment: I think the last significant change to the counter code in LaTeX was around 1985, I'm not sure if you consider that as recent.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Time (span) is relative, or at least the perception of it ;-)

Comment: @Herbert, it seems to be every table and figure has even-numbering only. I've tried decrementing the counter by 1, but that makes the counter stick at 0. It seems like the caption format code is running twice for every table and figure, since whatever counting changes I do, it seems to be done twice.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the code & book were written since 2008 and last typeset a few months ago, which means something has changed very recently. It is also not local to my computer since a teacher who downloaded the book's source reported the issue. (It's very bizarre!)

Comment: If something had changed in the latex format or in longtable, I would have known about it:-)

Comment: external links are discouraged (not good for the archives of this site) the normal advice is to start from a copy of the document and cut it down while still showing the error until it is small enough to paste inline into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented  the complete `\DeclareCaptionFormat` stuff in `styleV5.tex` 
and then it works. It makes absolutely no sense to me:

```
...
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% 8 Figures and Captions
% 8.1 Table Caption
%\DeclareCaptionFormat{nbTab}{Table\nobreakspace
  %\refstepcounter{withinChNum}\setcounter{table}{\value{withinChNum}}\setcounter{figure}{\value{withinChNum}}
%  \thechapter.\thewithinChNum:\nobreakspace#3}
%  \thechapter.\thewithinChNum:\nobreakspace#3}
%\captionsetup[table]{format=nbTab}
% 8.2 Figure Caption
%\DeclareCaptionFormat{nbFig}{Figure\nobreakspace\refstepcounter{withinChNum}\setcounter{table}{\value{withinChNum}}\setcounter{figure}{\value{withinChNum}}\thechapter.\thewithinChNum:\nobreakspace#3}
%\captionsetup[figure]{format=nbFig}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\let\c@table\c@figure
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 8.3 Caption Width
\newlength{\mycaptionwidth}
\setlength{\mycaptionwidth}{0.825\textwidth}
\setlength{\captionwidth}{\mycaptionwidth}


%-------------------------------------------------------------
% 9 Examples and Exercises
...
```

Comment: The goal of this code was to put the tables and figures on the same numbering. This keeps the numbering schemes within the text down to just two: one for figures / tables and one for everything else. So, this code (or some equivalent impact) is critical to keeping the text's numbering simpler.

Comment: Do you want to have `Table 1.1` and then `Figure 1.2`?? Looks totally weird to me.

Comment: That is how we do it. We originally tested the book with several numbering systems, but this new system makes it easier to find the table or figure of interest (especially tables... since the book can go for 10+ pages without a table to help one figure out if they should flip backwards or forwards to find the table they are looking for). First-world problem for sure!

Comment: see my edited answer. Insert the code between the two `%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%`

Comment: that's a way better solution than what we've been using, thanks! Just curious, any suggested references I should be reading up on to learn more about such options?

Comment: Not really ... Read the different answers to the questions and it gives you a lot of knowledge.